# SPFX: All search queries should be in URL

Tags: spfx

I making an SPFx. I need to made all my search parameters appear in URL.
I need to click on check box and add URL parameter like `https://sitename?ch=CheckBoxName`

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ck2 = this.domElement.querySelector("#contactChoice2");
    ck2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let search = location.search;
        search = search.replace(`?ck=notnull`, "");
        search = search.replace(`?ck=null`, "");
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + "?ck=notnull");
    });
```